# How to set awk variable in gnuplot?

Tags: bash, variables, awk, gnuplot, batch-processing

Present I can plot in batch like this

```
filename(n) = sprintf("x0%.3fgammamax.txt", n)
set term png size 800,600 enhanced
do for [ii=0:10]{
tempi=(ii+0.0)
outfile = sprintf('x0%.3fgammamax-pm3d.png',tempi)
set output outfile
splot filename(tempi) notitle with pm3d
}
```

But, Now I need to process the data before I plot using awk. The content of the file named addblanks.awk is

```
/^[[:blank:]]*#/ {next} # ignore comments (lines starting with #)
NF < 3 {next} # ignore lines which don't have at least 3 columns
$1 != prev {printf "\n"; prev=$1} # print blank line
{print} # print the line
```

If I don't need dynamic file name, I using the command:

```
splot "<awk -f addblanks.awk data.txt"  notitle with pm3d
```

However, I need dynamic file name still using awk now. The result should be like:

```
 splot "<awk -f addblanks.awk filename(tempi)"  notitle with pm3d
```

How to get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to concat the two string with the `.`:

```
splot "<awk -f addblanks.awk ".filename(tempi)  notitle with pm3d
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```
splot "<awk -v TEMPI="$tempi" -f addblanks.awk filename(TEMPI)"  notitle with pm3d
```

I have defined the awk variable with capital letters in order to prevent confusion. `tempi="$tempi"` should work as well.